# Scrolling GridView only on Button Click

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, layout

I want to achieve the following layout -

[image: Required Layout]

In this layout, I want to show all the available items to the user. Pressing right arrow will show the next 6 available items. This should happen via horizontal scrolling type motion.
Since items can be many, I want to use GridView for this because of its recycling optimisation. Optimisation is necessary because every item is a Linear Layout in itself.

Now, I can't use GridView because I want to show next 6 items using the arrows only. Also, it will be good if this happens in smooth scrolling type motion.

Can I make any tweak to Gridview so that I can use arrows to scroll GridView to show next 6 items or Is there any other ViewGroup available to achieve this along with the recycling optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is for listview you can refer for gridview also.

For a SmoothScroll with Scroll duration:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);
```

Parameters
position -> Position to scroll to
offset ---->Desired distance in pixels of position from the top of the view when scrolling is finished
duration-> Number of milliseconds to use for the scroll
Note: From API 11.

listview is quite lengthy and also with alphabet scroller. Then I found that the same function can take other parameters as well :)

To position the current selection:

```
int h1 = mListView.getHeight();
int h2 = v.getHeight();

mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, h1/2 - h2/2, duration);
```

Or

You can use RecyclerView :
You have to make use of LayoutManager for that. Follow the below steps.

1). First of all, declare LayoutManager in your `Activity/Fragment`. For example, I have taken `LinearLayoutManager`

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
```

2). Initialise the `LinearLayoutManager` and set that to your `RecyclerView`

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

3). On your Button `onClick,` do this to scroll to the bottom of your `RecyclerView`.

`mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourList.size() - 1);` // yourList is the ArrayList that you are passing to your RecyclerView Adapter.

Hope this will help..!!

Comment: Thanks !! It worked for me. However, my team liked it without scrolling so I used Joshua's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving corresponding list input to adapter at each click. And then call the `notifydatasetchanged` to reflect the changes on the `View`

Comment: But will Gridview do the recycling optimisation using your approach? Each item is a Linear Layout with many child views.

Comment: I would suggest using RecyclerView. If you are looking for a way to solve this using only GridView, I'm sorry I cant help you since I havent used it.

Comment: Yeah, I can use Recycler View. Can you tell how can I scroll recycler view on button click ? Thanks

Comment: I havent used scrolling in RecyclerView. You could set the RecyclerView to show your six icons at a time. Then with each click, change the icon list input to the RecyclerView. That way, 6 icons will be shown at a time. Which icons to show will be based on your input.

Comment: But again, if I use this approach, items are not recycled.

Comment: Dis you use notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter after each click?

Comment: Got you !! Let me try this. Thanks

Comment: Happy2help. ;) :)